# Onsen-uiでtabbarとslidemenuを共存させる方法

Tags: onsen-ui

以下のとおりSampleベースで書いたのですが、tabbarとslidemenuが競合しているのかどっちかしか動きません。両方成立させるためにはどうするべきでしょうか？ちなみにしたのコードだとtabbarしか動きません。

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html lang="ja">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>ons.bootstrap();</script>
  </head>
    <body>
        <ons-tabbar>
                <ons-tab page="home.html" label="Home" icon="ion-home" active="true"></ons-tab>
                <ons-tab page="comments.html" label="Comments" icon="ion-chatbox-working"></ons-tab>
                <ons-tab page="tags.html" label="Tags" icon="ion-ios-pricetag"></ons-tab>
                <ons-tab page="settings.html" label="Settings" icon="ion-ios-cog"></ons-tab>
    </ons-tabbar>

    <ons-sliding-menu
              main-page="index.html"
              menu-page="menu.html"
              side="left"
              max-slide-distance="250px"
              var="menu">
    </ons-sliding-menu>

    <ons-template id="home.html">
      <ons-page>
            <ons-toolbar>
                <div class="left">
                    <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggleMenu()">
                        <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" style="font-size: 32px; width: 1em;"></ons-icon>
                    </ons-toolbar-button>
                </div>
                <div class="center">Home</div>
            </ons-toolbar>
                <p style="padding-top: 100px; color: #999; text-align: center">Page Contents</p>
      </ons-page>
    </ons-template>

    <ons-template id="comments.html">
      <ons-page>
            <ons-toolbar>
                <div class="left">
                    <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggleMenu()">
                        <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" style="font-size: 32px; width: 1em;"></ons-icon>
                    </ons-toolbar-button>
                </div>
                <div class="center">Comments</div>
            </ons-toolbar>
                <p style="padding-top: 100px; color: #999; text-align: center">Page Contents</p>
                </ons-page>
    </ons-template>

    <ons-template id="tags.html">
      <ons-page>
            <ons-toolbar>
                <div class="left">
                    <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggleMenu()">
                        <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" style="font-size: 32px; width: 1em;"></ons-icon>
                    </ons-toolbar-button>
                </div>
                <div class="center">Tags</div>
            </ons-toolbar>
                <p style="padding-top: 100px; color: #999; text-align: center">Page Contents</p>
                </ons-page>
    </ons-template>

    <ons-template id="feed.html">
      <ons-page>
            <ons-toolbar>
                <div class="left">
                    <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggleMenu()">
                        <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" style="font-size: 32px; width: 1em;"></ons-icon>
                    </ons-toolbar-button>
                </div>
                <div class="center">Feed</div>
            </ons-toolbar>
                <p style="padding-top: 100px; color: #999; text-align: center">Page Contents</p>
                </ons-page>
    </ons-template>

    <ons-template id="settings.html">
      <ons-page>
            <ons-toolbar>
                <div class="left">
                    <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggleMenu()">
                        <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" style="font-size: 32px; width: 1em;"></ons-icon>
                    </ons-toolbar-button>
                </div>
                <div class="center">Settings</div>
            </ons-toolbar>
                <p style="padding-top: 100px; color: #999; text-align: center">Page Contents</p>
                </ons-page>
    </ons-template>

   <ons-template id="page1.html">
        <ons-page>
            <ons-toolbar>
                <div class="left">
                    <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggleMenu()">
                        <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" style="font-size: 32px; width: 1em;"></ons-icon>
                    </ons-toolbar-button>
                </div>
                <div class="center">page1</div>
            </ons-toolbar>
            <p style="text-align: center; color: #999; padding-top: 100px;">page1 Contents</p>
        </ons-page>
    </ons-template>

    <ons-template id="page2.html">
        <ons-page>
            <ons-toolbar>
                <div class="left">
                    <ons-toolbar-button onclick="menu.toggleMenu()">
                        <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" style="font-size: 32px; width: 1em;"></ons-icon>
                    </ons-toolbar-button>
                </div>
                <div class="center">Page 2</div>
            </ons-toolbar>
                <p style="text-align: center; color: #999; padding-top: 100px;">Page2 Contents</p>
        </ons-page>
    </ons-template>

    <ons-template id="menu.html">
        <ons-list><ons-list-item modifier="chevron" onclick="menu.setMainPage('page1.html', {closeMenu: true})">page1.html</ons-list-item>
            <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" onclick="menu.setMainPage('page2.html', {closeMenu: true})">page2.html</ons-list-item>
        </ons-list>
    </ons-template>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こんな感じでいかがでしょう。
ざっくり大事そうな所を書くと

1.`ons-sliding-menu`の`main-page`をタブバーを配置したhtmlに変更
 2.`menu.html`のリストクリック時の処理をアクティブタブの変更 + スライドメニューを閉じるに変更

となっています。

```js
ons.bootstrap();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.2.2/build/css/onsenui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.2.2/build/css/onsen-css-components.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.2.2/build/js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.2.2/build/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>

<ons-sliding-menu var="menu" menu-page="menu.html" main-page="tabbar.html" side="left" type="push" max-slide-distance="200px">
</ons-sliding-menu>

<ons-template id="tabbar.html">
    <ons-tabbar var="tabbar">
     <ons-tab page="home.html" label="Home" icon="ion-home" active="true"></ons-tab>
    <ons-tab page="comments.html" label="Comments" icon="ion-chatbox-working"></ons-tab>
    <ons-tab page="tags.html" label="Tags" icon="ion-ios-pricetag"></ons-tab>
    <ons-tab page="settings.html" label="Settings" icon="ion-ios-cog">   
    </ons-tab>
  </ons-tabbar>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="home.html">
  <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="left">
     <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggleMenu()"><ons-icon icon="bars"></ons-icon></ons-toolbar-button>
    </div>
    <div class="center">Home</div>
  </ons-toolbar>

  <p style="padding-top: 100px; color: #999; text-align: center">Home Page Contents</p>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="comments.html">
  <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="left">
     <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggleMenu()"><ons-icon icon="bars"></ons-icon></ons-toolbar-button>
    </div>
    <div class="center">Comments</div>
  </ons-toolbar>
  
  <p style="padding-top: 100px; color: #999; text-align: center">Comments Page Contents</p>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="tags.html">
  <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="left">
     <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggleMenu()"><ons-icon icon="bars"></ons-icon></ons-toolbar-button>
    </div>
    <div class="center">Tags</div>
  </ons-toolbar>
  
  <p style="padding-top: 100px; color: #999; text-align: center">Tags Page Contents</p>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="settings.html">
  <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="left">
     <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggleMenu()"><ons-icon icon="bars"></ons-icon></ons-toolbar-button>
    </div>
    <div class="center">Settings</div>
  </ons-toolbar>
  
  <p style="padding-top: 100px; color: #999; text-align: center">Settings Page Contents</p>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="menu.html">
  <ons-list>
    <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" onclick="tabbar.setActiveTab(0), menu.closeMenu()">
      Home
    </ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" onclick="tabbar.setActiveTab(1), menu.closeMenu()">
      Comments
    </ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" onclick="tabbar.setActiveTab(2), menu.closeMenu()">
      Tags
    </ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" onclick="tabbar.setActiveTab(3), menu.closeMenu()">
      Settings
    </ons-list-item>
  </ons-list>
</ons-template>
```